# Does there exist a field extension of the algebraic numbers $\mathbb{A}$ other than $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Does there exist a field extension of the algebraic numbers $\mathbb{A}$ other than $\mathbb{C}$?

---

I tried constructing one by adding $e$ to the algebraic numbers. We immediately get the group $\{a+eb; (a,b) \in \mathbb{A}^2\}$ but its easy to prove that this is not a field. So the extension must contain numbers like $\frac{1}{c+de}$, but these numbers are not closed under addition; when you add them, you get fractions where the numerators and denominators are polynomials  in $e$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{A}$.

So a natural proposition is to consider the set $\mathbb{A}(e)$, i.e the set of rational fractions of polynomials in $\mathbb{A}[x]$ evaluated at $e$. Its now easy to see that this is a field.

We can also verify that $\mathbb{A}(e)$ is a proper subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. Since $\mathbb{A}$ is countable, $\mathbb{A[x]}$ is too, and hence $\mathbb{A}(x)$ is countable as well since its the same thing as $\mathbb{A[x]}^2$. Thus $\mathbb{A}(e)$ is countable, and thus obviously not equal to $\mathbb{C}$.

Unfortunately, the degree of this extension, i.e $[\mathbb{A}(e):\mathbb{A}]$ is infinite. To prove this, suppose this space admits a basis with $n$ elements: $\{f_1(e),..f_n(e)\}$ where $f_1(x),...,f_n(x)$ are elements of $\mathbb{A}(x)$. Let $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_m\}$ be the set of poles of $f_1(x),...,f_n(x)$. Hence any linear combination of $f_1(x),...,f_n(x)$ has all of its poles lying in this set. Hence every element in $\mathbb{A}(e)$ can be written as $P(e)/[(e-\alpha_1)...(e-\alpha_m)]$ for some polynomial $P \in \mathbb{A}[x]$. Now take $a \in \mathbb{A}$ not lying in the set $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_m\}$. By the above, there exists $P \in \mathbb{A}[x]$ such that

$1/(e-a)=P(e)/[(e-\alpha_1)...(e-\alpha_m)]$.

So $e$ is a solution to $P(x)(x-a)-(x-\alpha_1)...(x-\alpha_m)]=0$. Since the LHS is a polynomial in $\mathbb{A}[x]$, all of its roots are algebraic and thus $e$ can only be a root if its the zero polynomial. But the LHS evaluated at $x=a$ is nonzero, a contradiction.

---

I'm not sure if what I wrote above is correct. Assuming it is, my question is **what are some other examples of field extensions of the algebraic numbers  $\mathbb{A}$ other than $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{A}(e)$?** In particular, are there any *finite* extensions?

Note: As Thomas Andrews noted, the argument above generalizes to $\mathbb{A}(\alpha)$ for any transendental $\alpha$. What I'm looking for is other examples...

Note 2: I have no background in field theory I just learned what is a field extension this morning, so forgive me if what I wrote above contains some badly wrong statements.

Comment: No. Any finite extension must be algebraic, pretty much by the argument you just gave. This is why there's a notion of [transcendence degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) for these sorts of questions. :)

Comment: I'm aware I made a typo in the question title. Fixed now.

Comment: The field $\mathbb A(e)$ is the field of rational function of $e$ with coefficients in $\mathbb A$. It is a field extension of $\mathbb A$, and is isomorphic to $\mathbb A(\pi)$ or $\mathbb A(\alpha)$ for any transcendental $\alpha$. None of these are isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ because they are all countable.

Comment: Yes, that is the construction I found above and I explained why they are countable, I am asking for other examples...

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou Take $\;\Bbb A(e,\,\pi)\;$ , if you want...something of transcendence degree greater than one. Anyway, the extension must be transcendent.\

Comment: $\Bbb A+e\Bbb A$ is not a ring, and it is not what you get when you adjoin $e$ to $\Bbb A$.

Comment: Yes I meant group of course. What do you mean its not what you get when you adjoin $e$ to $\mathbb{A}$? I added it to  $\mathbb{A}$ and then saw what else we would need to add to get a field.

Comment: If you want to be *really* pedantic about the phrase "adding $e$ to $\Bbb A$," what you would really get is $\Bbb A\cup\{e\}$, which is not even an additive group. You're automatically assuming you're getting all scalar multiples of it too. In the context of ring theory (well, commutative rings), if you adjoin an element, you're automatically adjoining all of its powers and their multiples.

Answer (score 5):

Formalizing, perhaps, a little more your work: if $\;K\;$ is a *finite* extension of $\;\Bbb A\;$, then for any $\;k\in K\;$ we get that $\;[\Bbb A(k):\Bbb A]<\infty\;$ , and thus there exists non zero

$$p(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0\in\Bbb A[x]\;,\;\;\text{s.t.}\;\;p(k)=0$$

But let us now take a look at $\;\Bbb Q(k, a_0,...,a_n)\;$ .  This is a finite extension of $\;\Bbb Q(a_0,...,a_n)\;$ , and this last is a finite extension of $\;\Bbb Q\;$ as $\;a_i\;$ algebraic for all $\;i\;$ . We thus get $\;\Bbb Q(k, a_0,...,a_n)\;$ is algebraic over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ and thus so is $\;k\;$, from which we get $\;k\in\Bbb A\implies K=\Bbb A\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

There are no finite extensions, because any such extension is algebraic.

There are however lots of infinite extensions.

For instance for any set $X$ of indeterminates you have the field $\mathbb A(X)$, which is the field of rational functions with variables picked from $X$ and coefficients in $\mathbb A$.

Note that $X$ can have any cardinality, giving you fields bigger than $\mathbb C$.